# How to float the label to the left and span to the right in the line?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is what the current code looks right now, I don't know why isn't it working
any help is appreciated,
Thanks!

Btw: It works when I set the parent div class to row, and style it with flex the same way.

```css
label {
  font-family:  Segoe UI;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #1E1E1E;
}

.field1 {
  font-family: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
      <div class="field1">
        <label>Username</label>
        <span class="holder">{{ form.username }}</span>
      </div>
```

Comment: It does seem to work..are you sure you're asking the right question?

Comment: Could you explain your issue? I'm seeing "username" on the left and `{{ form.username }}` on the right. Is this not what you are after? Your question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Add more info to the question

Comment: @chriskirknielsen Yh but I want it to work with "field1" and not "row"

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox will work, or you can remove flex and float the `.holder` right:

```css
label {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #1E1E1E;
}

.field1 {
  font-family: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.holder{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="field1">
  <label>Username</label>
  <span class="holder">{{ form.username }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like for me it was a Cache problem, so now it's working with parent div as "field1"